# encountered my Xamarin windows phone UWP app creation in visual studio 2017 RC

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I recently updated my **Visual Studio 2017 RC** and after update the PCL option were not shown in my Xamarin app, so I selected shared form app. While starting new project, it's given me an error and it does not created UWP project in solution explorer.

I have tried repair, reinstall every dependent of **VS2017 RC** but it's still giving me the same error:

> A problem was encountered creating the sub project 'App1.UWP. Unable
>   to copy the file 'Windows_TemporaryKey.pfx' form the project template
>   to project. Cannot find file
>   "C:\User\\AppData\Local\Temp\mnmdes3z.njy\Temp\Windows_temporaryKey.pfx"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Haven't encountered this problem before with **VS2017 RC** Not sure, but I hope this helps: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/18705/xamarinforms-solution-fails-to-create-uwp-project.html

or

https://twitter.com/Houssem_Dbira/status/831872617422397440